# Move to next open or closing parenthesis in VIM

Tags: vim, editor

I'm looking for a way to move to the next open or closing bracket of a certain type, e.g. `{` or `}`. Example:

```cs
if(true)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
       SomeFunction();
       SomeOtherFuntion();
   }
}
```

Let's say my cursor is on the 'S' in `SomeFunction()` and I want to jump to the next `}`, i.e. the end bracket of the for loop.

What is an efficient way to do this? The only way I can think of is using `/}[ENTER]`, but I'm wondering if there's a simpler way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at `:help motion.txt`, it contains all the various alternatives.

For `{` in the first column, there's `]]`. For unmatched ones, `]}`. In many languages, `{` represents the start of a method, then `]m` can be used. But in general, I see no problem with your suggestion of `/}<CR>`. If you use that often, you can always define a custom mapping for it:

```
:noremap ]] /}<CR>
```

Comment: The Problem with `/}<CR>` is that I use the pinky finger for all three of those keys, so it feels awkward. 
I'm familiar with `]]` etc. but I want the next one, regardless of if it is in the first column or not.

Thank you for your suggestion of ]m, it sounds promising, unfortunately it doesn't work in VsVim, so it seems mapping is the only way.

Comment: Why do you ask for a Vim feature if you want a VSVim feature?

Comment: Don't forget `[{` and `]}` to find the closest enclosing open or close brace.  Unfortunately these don't work in VsVim either.  Can you just install Vim at work?  (I use Vim to edit primarily but have VsVim installed for quick changes when I'm in the debugger.)

Comment: Thanks @dash-tom-bang, I was looking for your comment.

Answer (score 3):

Extending Ingo Karat's informative answer slightly, here's a custom mapping that remaps `]]` to start a search for the next `{` or `}` and `[[` does the same but in reverse:

```
:noremap ]] /[{}]<CR>  " Find next { or }
:noremap [[ ?[{}]<CR>  " Find prev { or }
```